Telerik Net Core Scheduler Custom Button Problem
I am currently working with Telerik Kendo UI for ASP.NET Core, version 2022.3.913. While trying to add a custom button to the scheduler component, I encountered an error in Visual Studio. The error message states:
"SchedulerToolbarFactory does not contain a definition for 'Custom' and no accessible extension method 'Custom' accepting a first argument of type 'SchedulerToolbarFactory' could be found."
This error suggests that the Custom method might not be available in the version of Telerik that I am using. I would like to understand which version of Telerik introduced the Custom extension for the scheduler component or if there might be a different mistake causing this issue. Could this be a version compatibility problem, or am I missing something in the setup?
Code:
    <div class="text-center">
        @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Bron.Models.Views.SchedulerModel>()
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Date(DateTime.Now.Date)
            .StartTime(DateTime.Now.Date)
            .MajorTick(60)
            .Toolbar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Custom().Text("My Custom Button").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "my-custom-button" });
                // You can add more custom toolbar items here
            })
...
            .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
            .Group(group => group.Resources("Locations", "Places").Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Vertical))
            .Resources(resource =>
            {
                resource.Add(m => m.LocationId)
                .Title("Локация")
                .Name("Locations")
                .DataTextField("name")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .DataSource(ds => ds.Read("GetList", "Locations"));
    
                resource.Add(m => m.Places)
                .Title("Номера")
                .Name("Places")
                .Multiple(true)
                .DataTextField("name")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .DataParentValueField("location_id")
                .DataSource(ds => ds.Read("GetList", "Places"));
               
            })
            .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.Id);
                m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
            })
            .Read("GetAll", "Home")
            .Create("Create", "Home")
            .Destroy("Timeline_Destroy", "Home")
            .Update("Timeline_Update", "Home")
            )
            .Editable(editable =>
            {
                editable.TemplateName("SchedulerEditorTemplate");
            })
            ....
           
            ))
            )
    </div>

